# Element is returned instead of the result of the method in my jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am developing a plugin for jquery and am having a problem to execute methods on it:

```
$(".data").bindFlexigrid("test")
```

In my plugin I have:

```
Plugin.prototype.test = function() {
    return "return this!!";
};
```

Using the debugging tool of Chrome I found that **my method is executed normally**

[image: Debugin plugin]

[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0zjF.png)

### The result is:

[image: Result]

[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGtHm.png)

**As you can see the result is not displayed**

The full plugin code in: https://gist.github.com/1725981

**The method is in line 141, but the problem with all methods**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
} else if (typeof options === "string" && options[0] !== "_" && options !== "init") {
        return this.each(function() {
```

By passing `"test"` you will hit this `if`.  `return this.each` will return `this` which is the jquery object.

`return` **within** the `each` has a different meaning.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Comment: On a related but not directly applicable note, the last line in your `init` function blows up.  `return $(this.container).flexigrid(this.opts.flexigrid);`  flexigrid doesn't exist, unless that's a different plugin.

Comment: Thanks, it's a different plugin.  
I think I understand why are returning an item. What should I change so that `$(".data").bindFlexigrid("test")` perform a method and returns the result of the method?

Comment: Problem is, you're storing the Plugin object on the individual elements.  What if there are no elements matching your selector, or those elements haven't been initialized?  You could loop over them and compile a return value, or just use the first element.

Comment: I found the solution ..   
`$(".MYSELECTOR").data("plugin_" + pluginName)`  
In this way recover the Plugin object and have access to all resources (and methods) of it.  
Anyway, thanks for the help.